# Controlling a browser using C# for streaming media

Tags: c#, webdriver, webbrowser-control, media-player, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to control a browser using C#. The way that used to work was OLE/interop. This seems to be missing from modern browsers. All I need it to do is be able to navigate to a URL and then change the URL from time to time. The problem using Process.Start("http://example.com") is this usually spawns several children processes and I can't determine the exact process to kill later. Calling it several times simply creates new children. I tried using the WebBrowser and WebView controls. Yes, these give me the control I want, but the rendering engine is embedded in the application and is so old, no sites allow these controls to work anymore.

I found something called WebDriver. At first this seemed like a good solution, except it appears to be very dependent on the exact build of the browser and has dependencies on Selenium. It probably works great for automated testing, I'm not convinced it will work well for long term browser control if the browser updates itself.

Next comes CefSharp. I've used this in the past, but it also seems to have an embedded and outdated rendering engine and many sites complain it too is out of date. And even if CefSharp gets updated from time to time, I need to rebuild my application each time. The problem I see here is, the rendering engine is embedded into an assembly that gets distributed with my app. Yes, I've seen a huge list of other embedded solutions. Many of them haven't been updated in years.

Ideally, I could control a browser using something like WebDriver that worked on any browser version. I could launch an external browser like FireFox or Chrome. Do any browsers have an API? Here's exactly the pseudo code I'd like to implement using a modern browser:

```
ModernBrowser br = new ModernBrowser();
br.Navigate("about:blank"); // clear out last page
if(some_flag)
    br.Navigate(Url); // navigate to new page.
If(done)
    br.Close();
br = null;
```

That is all I need. Dead simple.
I'm trying to implement a media playback system. All the code works fine except where I need a modern browser to play back Pandora, Spotify or any other web based systems. They all require the latest browser versions or they simply don't work. Embedding a rendering engine in my application is a nightmare. Sure, I can get it to work today. I'm just not sure about tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to try CefSharp and it works. I realize I'll have to update this from time to time. I want to point out that if you decide to use CefSharp as an embedded browser, don't use NuGet on your live project. Create a throw-away project and install the CefSharp assemblies. As of the date of this entry, the Nuget install breaks your C# project and makes every assembly unusable. What I did was I created a throw-away project, added the CefSharp assemblies and then took the dependent binaries and put them in a new folder. I made my live project an X86 target and that works.

Comment: Did you follow the post installation instructions? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/NuGet/Readme.txt until https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4158 is resolved extra steps are required.  The assemblies being unusable is a sign you've missed a step.